# What's the value of $\int \left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2} \right) dx$?

Tags: calculus

$$\int \left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)  dx$$

Also, What is it's value from $0$ to $(1+\sqrt7)/2$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Enclose the argument of the square root in curly braces {}

Comment: Can you integrate each piece, $1$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$?  The second is done by a trig substitution.  What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried to substitute $x = \sin(\theta)$?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201-sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%20from%200%20to%20%281%2Bsqrt%287%29%29%2F2):

$$ \int_0^{(1+\sqrt 7)/2} 1-\sqrt{1-x^2} dx = 1.03748+i0.785093$$

An alternative procedure is starting with the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(x)$:

Derivative of $\sin^{-1}$:
$$ \sin^{-1}(x)=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
Separating:
$$\sin^{-1}(x)=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx+\int(-x)\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)dx $$
By parts:
$$\sin^{-1}(x)=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx+(-x)(\sqrt{1-x^2})-\int(-1){\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $$
Reordering and adding $\int dx=x$:
$$\int 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=x-\frac 12 x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac 12 \sin^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be missing pieces or a mistake in the inquiry, here's why:

let x = sin(u)

Thus, $\frac{dx}{du}=cos(u)$
$$\int 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \int (1-cos(u))(cos(u))du $$
Using the Double angle formula: $cos(2\theta)=2cos^2\theta -1$ , we have:
$$ sin(u) - \int\frac{cos(2u)-1}{2}du $$ which thus evaluates to (using double angle formula $sin(2\theta)=2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$):
$$ sin(u)-\frac{1}{2}sin(u)cos(u)+\frac{1}{2}u + C $$
Substituting x back into the equation:
$$ x - \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}sin^{-1}x+C $$
Coming back to the original integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}}1-\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = [x - \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}sin^{-1}x]_{0}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}} $$

Here's where it doesn't make sense, the last part of the expression requires you to evaluate $$ sin^{-1}(\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}) $$
which will not be possible since $\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{2}$ lies outside the function domain of $sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: Your solution is exactly like mine. I arrived at the same thing, and thought maybe I was wrong. The thing is, I don't think there are missing pieces. This integral comes from trying to calculate the area under a semicircle whose diameter lies on the y-axis. Maybe I did something wrong. Can you give it a try?